# How do I add a footer row displaying row count to a matrix in SQL Reporting Services?

Tags: reporting-services, reportingservices-2005

I have a matrix on my report that is displaying a data set that contains one row for each person in a company:

> ```
> Company     Position   Name
> -------     --------   -----
> Acme Inc.   CEO        Bob
> Acme Inc.   COO        Alice
> Beta Corp.  CEO        Frank
> Beta Corp.  CTO        Rob
> Beta Corp.  COO        Bill
> (etc)
> ```

The matrix has a column grouping for Position, and a row grouping for Company. The final report looks like this:

> ```
>   Company        CEO      CTO     COO
> -----------------------------------------
> | Acme Inc.   |  Bob              Alice |
> | Beta Corp   |  Frank    Rob     Bill  |
> | Foo, Inc.   |           Paul          |
> | Bar Corp    |  Mary                   |
> ```

I want to add a footer row at the bottom of the matrix that counts how many CEOs, CTOs, etc there are.

> ```
> -------------------------------------
> People in role | 3         2        2
> ```

How do I do this in SQL Reporting Services 2005? Unfortunately, Matrix controls in SSRS 2005 don't seem so support footer rows like Table controls do. I think the solution will involve some trickery involving row groups, but I don't know enough about the Matrix control to figure it out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the Design view, right click on the "Company" cell and select Add Total-->After.

A new row will be added as a footer with "Total" in the left most cell.  To the right of totalm in the Title Column, enter the following expression:

```
=COUNT(Fields!Name.Value)
```

Preview the report and the Totals will be displayed exactly as you're looking for.

**Update**

The above answer is for SSRS 2008.  Since you're using SSRS 2005, take a look at Technique #5 in the following link: http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/reporting-services/advanced-matrix-reporting-techniques/

Comment: I don't see anything like that in the UI. Are you thinking of a table and not a matrix?

Comment: Ah, I was using SSRS 2008.  Too bad.  It's so simple in 2008.  I've updated my answer with a link you should check out.

Answer (score 2):

Simplest Solution I could find out was

=SUM(iif(Fields!Name.Value<>"",1,0))

where Fields!Name is data field in Matrix.

---

Please Mark this as an answer you find this helpful

Answer (score 1):

Can you try to use InScope function?

For example,

```
=IIF(InScope("nameOfColumnGrouping"), Sum(yourField.Value), do something)
```

You may have to specific the scope on Sum function also.

For example,

```
=IIF(InScope("nameOfColumnGrouping"), Sum(yourField.Value,"datasetName/groupName"), do something)
```

Hope this help!

Comment: Which column grouping should I be referring to? I already have one for the company, but when I use InScope("CompanyName") it's *always* in scope and the alternate condition never shows up.

Comment: I think it should be position not company. Something like =IIF(InScope("PositionGroup"), Sum(Fields!yrField.Value), 0.00).